# Почему при парсинге даты получаю различные значения?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, asp.net-web-api

Обращаюсь к внешнему API, получаю ответ. В ответе есть дата, я сохраняю файл с данными с именем "дата в ответе".
Вот так:

```
var response = await GetFromApiOnDate(date, token);
var fileDate = response.Item1.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ssZ");
data = response.Item2;
await SaveCacheJsonAsync($"{DirectoryPath}/{fileDate}.json", data);
```

При попытке парсинга даты из названия файла я получаю другую дату, нежели ту, что записана в имени. Вот пример как происходит парсинг:

```
var filesOnDate = files.Where(f =>
{
    var fileDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name),
        "yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ssZ",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return DateOnly.FromDateTime(fileDate) == date;
});
```

В fileDate получаю:
[image: fileDate]

Хотя на самом деле файл называется:
[image: Дата]

Как исправить это? И почему так происходит? Я так понимаю тут как то зависит от timeZone, хотя не знаю. Пробовал полученную дата преобразовывать в utc с помощью ToUniversalTime(), но не помогло.

Comment: Вангую проблема во временных зонах,  у вас где вы живёте +7 utc зона? Дата в имени файла в UTC, а дата на скрине в локальной зоне?

Comment: Да, дело в таймзонах. / Добавьте параметр `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` в метод `ParseExact`. / Смотрите свойство `fileDate.Kind` до добавления параметра - Local, и после - Utc.

Comment: Ещё как вариант можно вызывать метод `ToUniversalTime()` у `fileDate` для преобразования в Utc. При этом можно не использовать `DateTimeStyles`.

Comment: Ну и ещё как вариант, использовать `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`. При этом получится `DateTimeOffset` вместо `DateTime`. Во многих случаях правильнее использовать именно этот тип.